# Compiling Win32 and x64 csproj with different references

Tags: visual-studio, 64-bit, csproj

I would like to keep my `.csproj` projet and compile two version of the dll, one for `Win32` platform and the other for `x64` platform.

I hit a problem because I need to use different references for each platform

For example, for the ExternalReference.dll

```
 <Reference Include="ExternalReference">
   <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
   <HintPath>c:\win32_repository\ExternalReference.dll</HintPath>
 </Reference>
```

and for `x64`:

```
 <Reference Include="ExternalReference">
   <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
   <HintPath>c:\x64_repository\ExternalReference.dll</HintPath>
 </Reference>
```

I read about the `$(ReferencePath)` variable, but it seems to work only in the `.csproj.user` file and these files doesn't live on our version control, so this is not a solution.

Do you guys have any ideas ? Could I define a custom variable in the `.csproj` like this:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Platform)' == 'Win32' >
   <CustomReferencePath>c:\win32_repository</CustomReferencePath>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Platform)' == 'x64' >
   <CustomReferencePath>c:\x64_repository</CustomReferencePath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

and then add reference like this:

```
<Reference Include="ExternalReference">
   <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
   <HintPath>$(CustomReferencePath)\ExternalReference.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

But it doesn't seem to work, am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: .NET metadata doesn't have a dependency on bitness.  What's going on what that DLL?  Or is this just a matter of copying the right DLL into the build folder?

Comment: Hi, I wrote on extended a software with the sofware's libraries. Some of the libraries may not be .Net, anyway, I really want to use the correct dependencies, to be consistent with the extension design we use.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply:

```
<Reference Include="ExternalReference" Condition=" '$(Platform)' == 'Win32'>
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>c:\win32_repository\ExternalReference.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="ExternalReference" Condition=" '$(Platform)' == 'x64'>
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>c:\x64_repository\ExternalReference.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Comment: Doesn't work how? Didn't bring in the right assembly or failed to work at all?